# php echo single quote and it end javascript's script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have input type text for user to edit their text

```
<input type='text' id='about'>
$('#about').val('<?PHP echo $about;?>');
```

the reason I didn't use value is because I have a reset button can reset the form.

```
<input type='text' id='about' value='<?PHP echo $about;?>'>
```

if I place inside of value, the reset button will not working.

My problem is if user enter the text with `'` it will end the line from my script

```
ex.
$('#about').val('It's cool');
```

any way to solve this problem?

Comment: By escaping like `$('#about').val('It\'s cool');`

Comment: `$('#about').val('<?PHP echo addslashes($about);?>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addslashes()` is what you want, see below:

```
$('#about').val('<?PHP echo addslashes($about);?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do and it works for sure

```
<?php 
$data = "aa ' aaa ' aaa";
?>
<script>
var aa = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
alert(aa);
</script>
```

So in your case

```
$('#about').val('<?php echo json_encode($about);?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars() to escape the quote.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose your string in double quotes javascript as follow:

```
$('#about').val("<?PHP echo $about;?>");
```

Comment: And what if they want to use a double quote? ;)